# File zipped using 7za cannot be unzipped using zip utility

Tags: rhel, zip, 7z

I have created this file using 7za command called test.war

```
# file test.war
test.war: 7-zip archive data, version 0.4
```

I am trying to extract this file in another RHEL machine using command :

```
# unzip test.war
Archive:  test.war
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test.war or
        test.war.zip, and cannot find test.war.ZIP, period.
```

Does this mean I cannot unzip the file that has been created using 7zip?

Comment: Yes. 7zip is not the standard gnu zip. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip

Comment: @IporSircer, `zip` and `unzip` aren't GNU programs, they're part of the [Info-ZIP](http://info-zip.org/) project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, no, you can't extract the file using `unzip`; you need to use `7za` to extract it.

By default, `7za` creates [7z-format archives](http://www.7-zip.org/7z.html). It can also create zip-format archives, which can be extracted using `unzip`; to do so, either specify an archive with a `.zip` extension, or specify the type using `-tzip`:

```
7za a -tzip test.war ...
```

This will produce a `test.war` file which can be extracted with `unzip`.

Note that if you're creating a JavaEE WAR file you should use the `jar` tool anyway (or the appropriate plugin for your build tool), not `zip` or `7za`.

Answer (score 0):

The question (and comment) mention two types of programs:

- archivers (which compress their content)
- compressors (which compress a single file)

Generally, the later archivers/compressors can unarchive/uncompress those written by older tools.  For instance, [**`info-zip`**](http://www.info-zip.org/) (zip/unzip) was written to work with files created by [**`pkzip`**](https://www.pkware.com/pkzip) (a utility for MS-DOS).  [**`7zip`**](http://www.7-zip.org/) is another, much later archiver, which may work with files created by info-zip.

[**`gzip`**](http://www.gzip.org/) (GNU-zip) is a compressor and is unrelated to any of the above-mentioned tool.  Although written around the same time as **`info-zip`**, it was written to replace [**`compress`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/compress.html) and [**`uncompress`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uncompress.html) (Unix utilities).  These last are standard Unix utilities; none of the others are standardized.